# Jquery increase droppable snap threshold and reset it's position if a snap couldn't happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have these divs two are draggable with a snap two are droppable.

I can't find or figure a way to do the following:

- make both draggable divs and both droppable divs behave the same without massive copy pasting code.
- Increase the snap threshold to the point where the draggable div auto moves into place.
- If the draggable div is placed to little inside the droppable div it needs to be reset to it's last snapped location.\

I am only a beginner so please inform me with any wrongs in my post so I can edit it and learn from them.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" 
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      
      <style>
     #destination {
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     background-color: red;
    } 
    
     #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; background:#eee;}
   
    </style>
      
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ snap: "#destination" });
   $( "#destination" ).droppable();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div id="destination">
       destination
      </div>    

     
      <div id = "draggable">
         <p>Drag me !!!</p>
      </div>
     
      <div id="destination">
       destination
      </div>    
      
      <div id = "draggable">
         <p>Drag me !!!</p>
      </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

Set same attribute to draggable target and droppable target separately to avoid copy and paste.

Use `snapMode: 'inner'` make draggable div moves into place auto. And `snapTolerance` can change the threshold.

Finally, `revert:'invalid'` means draggable div will revert to last position if placed to little inside the droppable div.

If you want to make draggable1 pair to droppable1, you can add another attribute and pass accept option to `droppable()` init function.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" 
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      
      <style>
     [data-action='droppable'] {
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     background-color: red;
    } 
    
     [data-action='draggable'] { width: 150px; height: 150px; background:#eee;}
   
    </style>
      
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "[data-action='draggable']" ).draggable({ 
              snap: "[data-action='droppable']", 
              snapMode: 'inner',
              snapTolerance: 50,
              revert: 'invalid'
            });
            $( "[data-action='droppable']" ).droppable({
              accept: function(dragTarget) {
                return $(this).attr('data-pair') === $(dragTarget).attr('data-pair');
              }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div id= "destination1" data-action='droppable' data-pair='1'>
       destination1
      </div>    

     
      <div id = "draggable1" data-action='draggable' data-pair='1'>
         <p>Drag me1 !!!</p>
      </div>
     
      <div id= "destination2" data-action='droppable' data-pair='2'>
       destination2
      </div>    
      
      <div id = "draggable2" data-action='draggable' data-pair='2'>
         <p>Drag me2 !!!</p>
      </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain me what data-action='' means, and why did you use it ? I am trying to find it on the javascript documentation but with little luck

Comment: I think I got it, instead of selecting every separate  div, you just add a tag to it and then make the program work only with elements that have that tag?

Comment: `data-*` just an attribute to classify. You can use it as selector.